# extracting data with one query instead of multiple queries and deal with it easily

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for my bad english

i have a forms table in which i have columns like competition_name and team_name

secondly i have members table

each member has columns mem_name, mem_university , mem_team

means from has team_name and members also have team_name

one team can have several(upto 5) team members, i need to fetch all forms with their respective members in single query, and it should come into one array so that i can generate a table or a list, any idea?
which join should i use in this case, any dummy query for this scenario will be helpful
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking what the sql would be or the php code ?

Comment: You might want to look up [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) ([this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg) is helpful as well)

Comment: okie, let me modify my question

Comment: which join will be used here, inner join, left join?

Comment: You better show us table schema

Comment: INNER JOIN is used to avoid empty relations between tables

Comment: any dummy scenario for this query would be helpful

Comment: because You didn't provide table schema, so I can give You scenario where You collect team_name, comp_name in array then use query like: "select * from table where comp_name in (".implode(',' $comp_names).")"  than using joins. joins are not always fast.

most ORMs doing eager loading using "fieldname IN (param1, param2, ...)" style

Comment: schema has been attached in pics

Answer (score 0):

May be like this

```
SELECT forms.*,members.* 
FROM forms LEFT JOIN members ON forms.form_id=members.form_id 
GROUP BY forms.form_id
```